# Scalatra: Migrating Jersey Filters to Scalatra

Tags: scala, jersey, scalatra

I'm starting to dig into Scalatra but I have some extensive experience in Jersey.  One of the things I'm struggling with is how to get multiple filters for a controller in Scalatra?  For example, I have three unique filters:

1. CSRF
2. XSS
3. Authentication

Some of my controllers will only need 2 and 3, all will need 1, and others will only need 3.  In the future I may have more filters.  I understand the `before()` and `after()` methods, but those don't seem to help with the chaining I'm used to with Jersey.  Can someone help shed light on what I should be looking for?

Comment: Do your routes map well to the requirements?  For instance, do all of the ones that only require filter 3 follow a similar routing pattern (like /foo/bar/* or similar)?

Comment: Yes and no, but your answer below actually works out better.  I always hated having to look at the web.xml file to figure out what filter was applied to which controller, I like the before() filters much more for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have well defined routes that share a common pattern depending on what you want to do then you could do

```
def before("/pattern1/*") {
    CSRF
}

def before("/pattern2/*") {
    XSS
    CSRF
}

def before("/pattern*") {
    Authenticate
}
```

And so on.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that you could have multiple before() and after() patterns, that actually helps a lot.  Silly of me to miss that given that you can have other routes for the same HTTP type...  Thanks, this helps quite a bit!

Comment: No problem.  It helps that I work with, and got to confirm with Ross Baker (https://github.com/rossabaker) :)